# How to get gps.h into a Yocto recipe build?

Tags: gcc, yocto, bitbake, gpsd

I've built a simple recipe which works as long as I don't need `gps.h`:

```
recipes/foo (dunfell) $ cat foo_3.0.0.bb 
DESCRIPTION = "FOO Daemon"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = " file://*.* \
    "
S = "${WORKDIR}"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"

do_compile() {
    cd ${S}/src
    make
    cp foo ~/
    cd -
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 foo ${D}${bindir}
}
```

`gps.h` is in `/usr/include` on my local machine, but as Yocto is cross-compiling it provides a reasonable explanation of why it can't use the local `/usr/include/gps.h`:

```
cc1: error: include location "/usr/include" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Werror=poison-system-directories]
foo.c:54:10: fatal error: gps.h: No such file or directory
   54 | #include <gps.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

I've tried `IMAGE_INSTALL_append " libgps-dev"` and `" gps-lib-dev"` in my layer.conf but neither of those work.

How can I get the `gps.h` header into my Yocto project/recipe at build time?

Comment: Check my answer, if you can provide me the source code, I can try to validate the recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me copy your recipe and add some comments first:

```
DESCRIPTION = "FOO Daemon"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

# --- COMMENT ---
# It is not recommended to use "*" with SRC_URI, 
# as Yocto will not keep track of your files if you edit them 
# so it will never rebuild automaticall after a change
# Best practice is to sepecify the local files like:
# SRC_URI = "file://src"
# This will make bitbake unpacks the "src" folder into ${WORKDIR}
# --- COMMENT ---
SRC_URI = " file://*.* \
    "

# --- COMMENT ---
# The ${S} variable is the defautl workind directory for compilation tasks, 
# do_configure, do_compile, ..., 
# So, if you have "src" folder that will be unpacked into ${WORKDIR}
# you need to set S to that:
# S = "${WORKDIR}/src"
# --- COMMENT ---
S = "${WORKDIR}"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"

# --- COMMENT ---
# If your project has a "Makefile" you can use the "autotools" class
# it runs oe_runmake automatically
# inherit autotools
# If you want to copy the output to your home directory you can do it in "do_install"
# If you use autotools you do not need do_compile
# --- COMMENT ---
do_compile() {
    cd ${S}/src
    make
    cp foo ~/
    cd -
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 foo ${D}${bindir}
}

# --- COMMENT ---
# Do not forget to specify your output files into FILES for do_package to work well
# FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/foo"
# --- COMMENT ---
```

Now, after dealing with that, if your recipe requires something at build-time, than the dependency needs to exist in the same recipe's workding directory, because if you are adding libgps into `IMAGE_INSTALL` it will be present in the rootfs but not during your build time.

So, to do that, you need to specify the dependencies recipe with `DEPENDS`.

I have looked for `gps.h` and I found it packages with `gpsd` recipe.

So, try:

```
DEPENDS += "gpsd"
```

So, the final recipe would look like the following:

```
DESCRIPTION = "FOO Daemon"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://src"

S = "${WORKDIR}/src"

DEPENDS += "gpsd"

inherit autotools

do_install(){
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 foo ${D}${bindir}
    cp foo ~/
}

FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/foo"
```

The only thing left is to test.

Comment: Thanks, `DEPENDS += "gpsd"` as the critical line.  Can I use `inherit autotools` for a Makefile project that does not use autotools/autoconf?

Comment: You can use `autotools` for projects having only `Makefile`, `autotools` checks if there is `${S}/configure` before running `configure`, and then it runs `oe_runmake`. for more details check `poky/meta/classes/autotools.bbclass` check `autotools_do_configure` and `autotools_do_compile`

Comment: Why would you want to inherit the autotools class if it's not an autotools project? If you don't include a bbclass the base bbclass of BitBake will search for a Makefile and run it.

Comment: Yes that is actually true, I forgot about that. Thanks for mentioning that.